# Sensor Unity Snap App- Need to get the information of this app after installation

Tags: 19.04, snap

Snap store recommended to install Sensors Unity app through the Ubuntu Store and so I installed the Sensors-Unity app using the Ubuntu Desktop store!

[Sensors Unity Ubuntu Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke8Fk.png)

I clicked the launch button but it's not working. Not even a blank screen appears.  I tried to launch this app on Terminal but it says

**E: Unable to find**

I need to know the complete information about this application that installed in my Ubuntu pc. I'm new to this platform, need a simple Terminal command to know the information about this application.

PC: Asus Vivobook S

OS: Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I got something that you installed the Sensors-unity app from Ubuntu Store but it won't launch and so you need to information about Sensors-Unity Application!

After installing the application, you can find the information about the app using the following command:

```
$ sudo snap info sensors-unity
```

It will ask you the system password, provide the password and execute the command.

The complete information about the application will display in the Terminal as shown in the below example.

```
name:      sensors-unity
summary:   A simple sensors GUI for Unity & Dash to Dock
publisher: Pavel Rojtberg (paroj)
contact:   https://github.com/paroj/sensors-unity
license:   unset
description: |
  Allows monitoring the output of the `sensors` command graphically.

  **Note:** for sensors-unity to work you have to manually give it the
  hardware-observe permission in the software center or using the CLI as:

  snap connect sensors-unity:hardware-observe :hardware-observe

commands:
  - sensors-unity
snap-id:      0i0ACucdvIfcOKZgDUIrd7AsRoolk6US
tracking:     stable
refresh-date: today at 22:54 IST
channels:
  stable:    18.02 2019-06-26 (103) 75MB -
  candidate: ^                           
  beta:      ^                           
  edge:      18.02 2019-07-24 (119) 75MB -
installed:   18.02            (103) 75MB -
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this method now!!

Comment: The command `sudo snap info <package-name>` can be used to find the information about any Snap Store applications. Replace the <package-name> with your snap application.

Comment: Thanks for the command explanation, The answer that you mentioned above is worked for me! I will try this command to find the information about the snap apps that I installed in my pc.